# Reverse pinvoke, call C# object's method from native C/C++ DLL without CLI/CLR

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke

I want to make a C++ class that wraps a reference to a managed object existing in a win forms application so that it can be manipulated from both sides (C# and C++).

This object will be accessed asynchronously from C++. For this I would like to store a reference to that managed object in the native code. I know the GC can collect it so I read that I should reference it somewhere in the managed code to prevent this.

My question is : is it possible to store a reference to a managed object in a native DLL (without using CLI/CLR stuff) and use it to call methods asynchronously ? And if yes, what is the syntax for passing the object ? Also what about the methods of that managed object ? Do i also need to store a reference to them in my native code ?

Thank you. :)

Comment: COM is the cleanest way to implement this

Comment: *My question is : is it possible to store a reference to a managed object in a native DLL (without using CLI/CLR stuff)* At some level, you have to tell the CLR that you don't want an object to be collected. You can keep a reference in a static property, you can pin it directly with GCHandle, you can use COM, but the truth is that you have to tell the CLR.

Comment: Isn't the CLR some kind of C++ extension ? Is it part of C# ? By without CLI/CLR i meant that i want to use the standard C++, not MS's extended C++.

Comment: @Virus721 No, the CLR is the Common Language Runtime, the .NET virtual machine. Two important parts of the CLR are the one that compiles from IL code to machine code and the Garbage Collector

Answer (score 0):

**I'm writing this in the hope that David Heffernan will correct me and teach me something :-)**

As I've written in the comment:

*My question is : is it possible to store a reference to a managed object in a native DLL (without using CLI/CLR stuff)*

At some level, you have to tell the CLR that you don't want an object to be collected. You can keep a reference in a static property, you can pin it directly with `GCHandle`, you can use COM, but the truth is that you have to tell the CLR.

Using COM objects is complex (at least for me :-) ).

What I would do:

Given a `MyClass`, with an object created C#-side, with a `DoSomething` method that I want to use both C# and C++ side.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;

    public bool DoSomething(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return Name.Length == value1 || Surname.Length == value2;
    }
}
```

I would create a `MyProxyClass` like this:

```
public class MyProxyClass
{
    private delegate void FreeMeDelegate();

    [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    private delegate bool DoSomethingDelegate(int value1, int value2);

    private GCHandle Handle;
    private DoSomethingDelegate DoSomething { get; set; }

    // You pass this function pointer to C++. Its signature is:
    // bool(__stdcall *DoSomething)(int32_t, int32_t)
    public IntPtr DoSomethingPtr { get; private set; }

    private FreeMeDelegate FreeMe { get; set; }

    // You have to pass this function too to C++. C++ code must use it
    // to free MyProxyClass. Its signature is:
    // void (__stdcall *FreeMe)(void)
    public IntPtr FreeMePtr { get; private set; }

    public void FreeMeImpl()
    {
        if (Handle.IsAllocated)
        {
            Handle.Free();
            DoSomething = null;
            DoSomethingPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            FreeMe = null;
            FreeMePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    public MyProxyClass(MyClass obj)
    {
        Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Normal);

        // This will implicitly create a reference to obj. GC can't
        // collect MyProxyClass because we have a GCHandle on it,
        // and can't collect obj because there is a delegate that
        // has a reference on it.
        DoSomething = obj.DoSomething;
        DoSomethingPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(DoSomething);

        FreeMe = FreeMeImpl;
        FreeMePtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(FreeMe);
    }
}
```

This class when created automatically stops the GC from collecting her. Then creates some `IntPtr` delegates to the method `DoSomething` and to a `FreeMe` method, that the C++ code will need to use to free it.

Now, C#-side:

```
MyClass myclass = ...; // you instance of myclass

var proxy = new MyProxyClass(myclass);

// Now you pass these to C++
//proxy.DoSomethingPtr;
//proxy.FreeMePtr;
```

Comment: This is all over my head. Me, I'd use COM, or C++/CLI mixed mode, or UnmanagedExports.